# How to sum all stock and add in total from table?

Tags: laravel

This is my index.blade.php.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Product Name</td>
            <td>Stock</td>      
        </tr>   
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($products as $product)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$product->name}}</td>
            <td>{{ $product->getProductStock() }}</td>  
        </tr>
        @endforeach 
    </tbody>    
</table>
```

I am getting this result from above code.

```
| Product Name | Stock  |
|     Mobile           |   32     |
|    Laptop            |  45      |
```

But am expecting this result.So how to add all stock from and and put in total ?

```
| Product Name | Stock  |
|     Mobile           |   32     |
|    Laptop            |  45      |
|     Total              |     77    |
```

Comment: Have you looked at Laravel `sum()` method? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-sum

Comment: @MiqayelSrapionyan Can you give small demo please ?

Comment: Can you tell me the field name in the database, to sum the total with that field?

Comment: stock is field name of my database but i want to add getProductStock() because i have written stock of single product and i want to stock from given all product

Comment: so I think `$products->sum('stock')` will work for you, outside of `foreach` loop

Answer (score 0):

You must calculate sum in your **Model** file, then pass to **Controller**, then pass to your  index.blade.php file.
But fast(not good) decision you can see here:

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Product Name</td>
        <td>Stock</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @php
        $sumAllProductsStock = 0;
    @endphp
    @foreach($products as $product)
        @php
            $sumAllProductsStock += $product->getProductStock()
        @endphp
        <tr>
            <td>{{$product->name}}</td>
            <td>{{ $product->getProductStock() }}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
        <tr>
            <td>sum</td>
            <td>{{$sumAllProductsStock}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Product Name</td>
            <td>Stock</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @php
        $sumproductsstock = 0;
        @endphp
        @foreach($products as $product)
        @php
        $sumproductsstock = $sumproductsstock +  $product->getProductStock();
        @endphp
        <tr>
            <td>{{$product->name}}</td>
            <td>{{ $product->getProductStock() }}</td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td>Total Stock</td>
            <td>{{$sumproductsstock }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
$products->sum('qty');
```